# cryptdisk login fail after today's upgrades

Tags: encryption

Ubuntu doesn't recognize the cryptdisk passphrase after update today:

```
warning: failed toconnect to lvmetad.falling back to device scanning.
volume group ubuntu-vg not found.
cannot process volume group ubuntu -vg.
please unlock disk sda3_crypt
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Did you try booting from a previous kernel? If you have them, have you tried restoring your LUKS headers to the encrypted partition?

Comment: Booting from previous kernels didn't solve anything, it seems my cyrillic keyboard was somehow preserved after restart of updates. Tried alt codes, that don't work. Tried tips through grub 2 to change initrams, that didn't work. All my sensiive data was backed up, so made a fresh reinstall:)